# Integrating partial fractions so $x(t)$ is subject

Tags: calculus, integration

So I've got $\frac{dx}{dt} = bx(1-x)$ and I need to find the general solution for $x(t)$.

I've separated it into partial fractions:

$$\frac{1}{x(1-x)} = \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{1-x}$$

Which leads to $\ln(x/1-x) = bt + C$ and then when I apply the exponent function:

$$\frac{x}{1-x} = e^{C\cdot e^{bt}}$$

How can I get $x(t)$ to be the subject? Thanks :)

Comment: This is elementary algebra, you shouldn't be asking that question ! (I am not trying to be rude, but someone dealing with ODE's should be able.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x(t)=\frac {e^{C}e^{bt}} {1+e^{C}e^{bt}}$. To derive this write $x=(1-x)e^{C}e^{bt}=e^{C}e^{bt}-xe^{C}e^{bt}$. Take the last term to the left side to get $x[1+e^{C}e^{bt}]=e^{C}e^{bt}$. Now divide by  $1+e^{C}e^{bt}$

Comment: Awesome, thank you :)